# How to use app.get asynchronously in express.js?

Tags: express, async-await

I am a beginner with express.
In my index.js
I have the following code :

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  var gui = guiText("index", lang);
  //var gui =  [ 'Activities', 'Declensions', 'Conjugations' ];
  res.render("index", {gui: gui});
  console.log ("sent gui", gui)
  })
```

guiText("index", lang) is a async function that calls a sqlite db to get the localized text.
When run this code, I can see that res.render is sent before guiText() has returned so my gui is empty.  If I uncomment

```
//var gui =  [ 'Activities', 'Declensions', 'Conjugations' ];
```

and comment out

```
var gui = guiText("index", lang);
```

my html file correctly gets the information it needs to display.
If I try

```
var gui = await guiText("index", lang);
```

I got the message  as it is not possible. How I can work around this problem?

Edit : upon  Heiko Theißen suggestion (this a very interesting post, but not very easy for a beginner), I tried to use a callback.
my guiText function is  now :

```
 guiText(page, lang, myCallback){
```

and ends with

```
 myCallback("index",{gui:result});
```

This function is called by :

app.get('/',  (req, res) => {
guiText("index", lang, app.res.render);

but I get the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'render')

How should I write the callback ?

Comment: Change `(req, res) => {` to `async (req, res) => {`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still have the same problem.
Console output still shows that the function doesn't wait guitText to return.
sent gui Promise { <pending> }
result [ 'Activities', 'Declensions', 'Conjugations' ]

Comment: `app.get('/', (req, res) => {guiText("index", lang, res.render.bind(res))})`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  var gui = await guiText("index", lang);
  //var gui =  [ 'Activities', 'Declensions', 'Conjugations' ];
  res.render("index", {gui: gui});
  console.log ("sent gui", gui)
  })
```

You can see that all I did was add the `async` keyword before `(req, res)` and `await` before `guiText("index", lang);` `await` wasn't working when you tried it because you forgot to make the entire app.get callback an async function.

Comment: Thanks. This is the simplest solution, but at least with the former one, I've learned how to use a callback!

Comment: So is [asyncHandler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler) now obsolete?

Comment: @MarinosAn No, asyncHandler is used as a wrapper around an async express callback. It catches errors and passes them to your error handler callback. You can still use asyncHandler with this solution